# Why does the Log4j2 Appenders not add the first log in the next line to the header?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am creating a log4j2 logger programmatically and adding appenders to it.
But one thing I notice is that **at the time of first log message** to be written, the log message gets appended to the header.

For example

```
header[2020-01-21 21:16:07,176][ERROR] - the error message
[2020-01-21 21:16:07,176][ERROR] - text message
```

What was expected was :

```
header
[2020-01-21 21:16:07,176][ERROR] - the error message
[2020-01-21 21:16:07,176][ERROR] - text message
```

Below is the code snippet I am trying to achieve this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Log4j2TestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Log4j2TestApplication.class, args);
    String loggerName = "testLogger";
    final ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

    final LoggerComponentBuilder loggerComp = builder.newLogger(loggerName, Level.ALL).addAttribute("additivity",
            false);

    builder.add(loggerComp);
    builder.setConfigurationSource(null);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    ctx.start(configuration);
    ctx.updateLoggers(configuration);
    Logger logger = ctx.getLogger(loggerName);
    Appender textAppender = createTextAppender(configuration);
    textAppender.start();
    logger.addAppender(textAppender);
    logger.error("the error message", "Test Paramter");
    logger.error("text message", "Test Paramter");
    textAppender.stop();
}

private static Appender createTextAppender(final Configuration config) {

    final Layout<String> layout = getTextLayout(config, "header");

    return RollingFileAppender.newBuilder().setConfiguration(config).setName("txtAppender")
            .withFileName("TestFile.text").withFilePattern("TestFile.txt")
            .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("100M"))
            .withStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder().withConfig(config).build()).withImmediateFlush(true)
            .setFilter(ThresholdFilter.createFilter(Level.ALL, Result.ACCEPT, Result.DENY)).setLayout(layout)
            .build();
}

private static Layout<String> getTextLayout(final Configuration config, final String header) {
    return PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config).withCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .withPattern("[%d][%-5.-5p] - %m%n").withHeader(header).build();
    }
}
```

Why is this behaviour and how we can make the first message to second line ?

Comment: Where you are appending `loggerName` ??

Comment: Your sample output shows "dummyHeader" but your code shows "header". If you want a newline then change that to "header\n".

Comment: I am sorry, I think I could not understand, why I should append loggerName and where it is expected to be appended?

Comment: @rgoers It was just for reference but I changed to the outputs as per program.Also you are correct "header\n" worked.Thanks, but IMHO the default behaviour from logger should not be to append to the header but log the message to the next line.

Comment: It is that way because it is easy to say you want a new line and very difficult to say you don't want one.

Comment: @rgoers, I think as your comment answers the question, you may consider it posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample output shows "dummyHeader" but your code shows "header". If you want a newline then change that to "header\n".